# How to display one collapse at a time with bootstrap 3 or 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building a website from a scratch using Bootstrap 4 and got stuck on an issue that may be easy for experienced Bootstrap developer. I found and came up with a solution on how to collapse one element at a time using raw Javascript code, but how can I achieve this using Bootstrap 4 or should I stick to this type of solution?? I will appreciate for any hint as I tried data-toggle / data-target / and seems like I am missing something to make it happen right. Not very strong in JS syntax, but have an understanding on it. See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4m1L215):

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
            <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >collapse</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
            <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >collapse</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px;">
            <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >collapse</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
      var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
                  name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
                  if (name == 'newboxes') {
                        if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                  }
                  else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to work for me. Only one `div` is displayed when I click the links. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: if you dont mind a bit of jquery try this, its more simple http://jsfiddle.net/m4m1L215/1/

Comment: yes, this code works fine and my goal is to make it as you see in fiddle, but how can I make it using bootstrap  4 with buttons, I try to achieve using bootstrap 4 collapse functionality:
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/
@ordonezalex

Comment: I think I am steering wrong way by explaining my apologies so I have made an example on test server and this what I have achieved with botstrap on this test server http://sintra.craftpearl.com/demo.php

The question is, how can I make this to be like here, but with boostrap 4:
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/m4m1L215/">jsfiddle</a>

@Carsten

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it by using [Bootstrap Accordian](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example). 
Check this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example